# AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I've got a quite busy server: PHP (Wordpress) using W3TotalCache APC, Varnish for Apache and Cloudflare to handle all traffic.
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Only one website with an average about 60k hits/day.

I get this message every now and then, few times a day. Has nothing to do with temporarily traffic spikes, we compared times with Google Analytics.

```
Thu Apr 28 14:14:42.938075 2016] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 19137] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
[Thu Apr 28 15:43:25.594147 2016] [core:notice] [pid 19137] AH00051: child pid 19866 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Apr 28 15:43:25.594313 2016] [core:notice] [pid 19137] AH00051: child pid 20386 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Apr 28 15:43:25.594407 2016] [core:notice] [pid 19137] AH00051: child pid 19143 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Apr 28 15:43:25.594498 2016] [core:notice] [pid 19137] AH00051: child pid 19144 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Apr 28 15:43:25.594572 2016] [core:notice] [pid 19137] AH00051: child pid 20597 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Apr 28 15:43:25.594642 2016] [core:notice] [pid 19137] AH00051: child pid 20395 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Apr 28 15:43:25.594704 2016] [core:notice] [pid 19137] AH00051: child pid 20424 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Apr 28 15:43:25.594785 2016] [core:notice] [pid 19137] AH00051: child pid 20598 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Apr 28 15:43:25.594870 2016] [core:notice] [pid 19137] AH00051: child pid 19861 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Apr 28 15:43:25.594957 2016] [core:notice] [pid 19137] AH00051: child pid 19782 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
....
....
```

So I've increased MaxRequestWorkers first to 100, then 500, now its at 1024. But still happening.

This is my apache2.conf at the moment.
Code:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
StartServers 256
MinSpareThreads 256
MaxSpareThreads 256
MaxClients 256
ServerLimit 256
ThreadLimit 256
ThreadsPerChild 256
MaxRequestWorkers 1024
MaxConnectionsPerChild 0
MaxRequestPerChild 1000
</IfModule>
```

There is a lot of free RAM, and load average is around 0.5, sometimes over 1. But never seen it higher then 2. So server seems healthy to handle the traffic.

```
top - 16:07:47 up 3 days, 18:18,  2 users,  load average: 0.57, 0.46, 0.55
Tasks: 113 total,   1 running, 112 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 10.5 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 87.4 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8176816 total,  2372560 used,  5804256 free,   189684 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.  1286692 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                              
21930 www-data  20   0  337212  83308  60072 S  24.9  1.0   0:52.89 apache2                                                                                                                                              
21945 www-data  20   0  327640  72684  58816 S  24.3  0.9   0:48.37 apache2                                                                                                                                              
 1182 nobody    20   0  702868 442268  83496 S   0.7  5.4  42:41.32 varnishd
```

Any ideas why Apache interrupts?

//j

Comment: I increased MaxRequestWorkers to 5000, server been stable for over 24h now. The longest for last few weeks without having to reboot apache.

Comment: Traffic have increased to about 2M hits per day and we get same issues.

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
StartServers 1024
MinSpareThreads 1024
MaxSpareThreads 1024
MaxClients 1024
ServerLimit 1024
ThreadLimit 1024
ThreadsPerChild 1024
MaxRequestWorkers 8192
MaxConnectionsPerChild 0
MaxRequestPerChild 4096
</IfModule>

Is there anything more you can do without adding more servers?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basically config got overwritten in:
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf

I put the new setting in that file and it seems Apache works correctly now.

Hopefully this helps someone else, don't put your config straight in apache2.conf or httpd.conf. Make sure you change all loaded config files.

Comment: I'm glad it seems to be resolved for you, but when you say "I put the new setting in that file", which setting are you referring to? What was the old value and what was the new value?

Comment: Downvoting: This response is not useful to anyone else - you do not include what change(s) you actually made or give any instruction as to what someone else with this problem could do to resolve it. Please update with useful information/snippets of config/key-value-pairs that you replaced/etc.

Comment: @MattRabe Downvoting for what? The provided answer is completly understandable unless you are not familiarized with Apache or... Linux directories / files.

Comment: @LucianoFantuzzi OP selected their own answer as correct despite not including all relevant information. "the new setting"... One can infer the key & value from the rest of the page, but this answer in and of itself still lacks that completeness. If OP would make minor edits to include key & value then I'm all for it!

Answer (score 33):

you should edit `mpm_prefork`

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
      StartServers                     10
      MinSpareServers               10
      MaxSpareServers              20
      ServerLimit                      2000
      MaxRequestWorkers         1500
      MaxConnectionsPerChild    10000
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Amazon Linux 2, file [need be created](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-apache-memory-tuning/)

Comment: Is it normal that ServerLimit < MaxConnectionsPerChild ?

Comment: Can someone explain what this all means? In other words, what is the cause? What is edited in what way? Why does that edit work?

Answer (score 9):

You modified the wrong file. Your log says "mpm_prefork" error. So you need to modify mpm_prefork.conf rather than mpm_worker.conf.

You can also use "apachectl -M" to see what module you are using.
e.g. My apache2 is using mpm_event_module, so i need to modify mpm_event.conf

```
$ apache2ctl -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 **mpm_event_module (shared)**
 negotiation_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 wsgi_module (shared)
```

Comment: +1 nice hint! Read this doc
https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-apache-web-server-performance/#prefork-mpm
to see the difference between the three modules to use and configure the correct one.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I couldn't find any solution, so I'm going to leave this answer here to help anyone else having this issue. In our case, increasing the MaxRequestWorkers didn't help.

We had a server that had been working fine for one year at least. All of a sudden, it began to have issues to connect to https. In the apache error logs, we found a "Server reached MaxRequestWorkers" error, but the traffic was very slow (30 - 40 visitors active).

After a deep look at logs and some research, I found that the issue was a [Slowloris DoS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security)).

The attack is easy to mitigate. You could take a look at [this post](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/slow-http-dos-attacks-mitigate-apache-http-server/).

Answer (score 4):

I also tried to increase `MaxRequestWorkers` on my server, and I was not seeing any effect. I realized what was going on when I ran "httpd" from the command line, it gave me this warning:

```
AH00180: WARNING: MaxRequestWorkers of 512 exceeds ServerLimit value of
 256 servers, decreasing MaxRequestWorkers to 256.
 To increase, please see the ServerLimit directive.
```

In your config, `ServerLimit` is still 256, so `MaxRequestWorkers` is capped by this value too.

Comment: See Yort's solution: if ServerLimit isn't listed in your config, it's 256 by default. So you need to add the respective line with a value equal or higher than MaxRequestWorkers.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check your webserver access log. You may be the target of an xml-rpc attack in case the log is flooded with xml-rpc posts(e.g. "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 200 403). There are various ways to prevent it from happening, but Wordpress is prone to this.

Comment: Can I ask you if I find xmlrpc requests in my access log, but not too much.. is this still considered as attack?

Comment: Yes, there are many automated attacks that target xmlrpc. Even if you don't have that file, they try anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after a low response speed, firstly I increased `MaxRequestWorkers` from 150 to 500. But with a warning in the apache `error.log`, I realized that I should also increase `ServerLimit` because its default value was 256. Besides, I did not found `ServerLimit 256` in `mpm_prefork.conf` so I added `ServerLimit 512` as a new line in it and the problem solved.